# Trouble separating G0 and G1 rules in grammar

Tags: perl, parsing, tokenize, marpa

I'm trying to get what seems like a very basic Marpa grammar working. The code I use is below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Marpa::R2;
use Data::Dumper;
my $grammar = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new(
    {
        source => \(<<'END_OF_SOURCE'),
            :start ::= ExprSingle
            ExprSingle ::= Expr AndExpr

            Expr ~ word

            AndExpr ~ word*
            word ~ [\w]+

            :discard ~ ws
            ws ~ [\s]+
END_OF_SOURCE
    }
);
my $reader = Marpa::R2::Scanless::R->new(
    {
        grammar => $grammar,
    }
);
my $input = 'foo';
$reader->read(\$input);
my $value = $reader->value;
print Dumper $value;
```

This prints `$VAR1 = \'foo';`. So it recognizes one word just fine. But I want it to recognize a string of words

```
my $input='foo bar'
```

Now the script prints:

```
Error in SLIF G1 read: Parse exhausted, but lexemes remain, at position 4
```

I think this is because `ExprSingle` uses the `~` (match) operator, which makes it part of the tokenizing level, G0, instead of the structural level G1; the `:discard` rule allows space between G1 rules, not G0 ones. So I change the grammar like so:

```
ExprSingle ::= Expr AndExpr
```

Now no warning is printed, but the resulting value is `undef` instead of something containing `'foo'` and `'bar'`. I'm honestly not sure what that means, since, before, the failed parse threw an actual error.

I tried changing the grammar to separate what I think are G0 and G1 rules further, but still no luck:

```
:start ::= ExprSingle
ExprSingle ::= Expr AndExpr

Expr ::= token

AndExpr ::= token*
token ~ word
word ~ [\w]+

:discard ~ ws
ws ~ [\s]+
```

The final value is still `undef`. `trace_terminals` shows both 'foo' and 'bar' being accepted as tokens. What do I need to do to fix this grammar (by which I mean get a value containing the strings 'foo' and 'bar' instead of just `undef`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rules by default return a value of undef, so in your case a return of \undef from $reader->value() means your parse succeeded.  That is, a return of undef means failure, while a return of \undef means success where the parse evaluated to undef.

A good, fast way to start with a more helpful semantics is to add the following line:

:default ::= action => ::array

This causes the parse to generate an AST.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm really excited to learn Marpa. Which document contains the list of `:default` actions I can use?

Comment: Thanks for your interest.  The list is in https://metacpan.org/module/JKEGL/Marpa-R2-2.058000/pod/Scanless/DSL.pod under "Actions".